# Fix overscan in DialogFragment title in Android TV

Tags: android-tv, dialogfragment

I have this problem that seems simple, but I can not find a solution anywhere...

As you probably know, an Application that is intended to run in an Android TV, should take into consideration the [overscan](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts#overscan).

So, as described in the link above, I added the border in my television layouts.

The problem is: what to do with the DialogFragment title? The title is out of my layout...

I want to keep the title, because there is a title in the normal application for other devices.

I just want the title to take the overscan into consideration and be placed a bit lower, so that it is not hidden.

Someone has a solution?
Possibly not a hack like moving the title string inside the fragment or similar :)

Comment: Have you considered using a [GuidedStepFragment](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/guided-step) instead of a DialogFragment? Android TV recommends using the [wizard pattern](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/android-tv/patterns/dialog.html) for dialogs which mirrors the layout of the guided step components.

Comment: Hi Michael. Well, actually I haven't look at it yet for two motivations: 1. they are just confirmation dialogs, I thought Step fragments where used when you must ask the user more choices, not just a "Yes/No" question 2. I would like my TV app looks exactly the same (as much as possible) to the normal app for smartphone. I haven't investigated yet, can I use GuidedStepFragment in a normal smartphone? How they will look like? Do you think I should investigate it?

Comment: GuidedStepFragment should only be used on a leanback device, not a smartphone. However, I would challenge the assertion that your apps need to look exactly the same across phone and TV. For the purposes of branding, it's important to keep a similar style and color scheme, but you shouldn't break the user experience for branding. A DialogFragment works on mobile, but Android recommends GuidedStepFragment on TV. It's one of those tradeoffs that I'd recommend making to stick with platform conventions.